# What is MariaDB's default password on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, mariadb

I installed the `mariadb-server` package on CentOS 7 with the command:

```
sudo yum install mariadb-server
```

The installation completed successfully, but I can't seem to log in to the server. Usually, a default MariaDB installation has no password, so I tried leaving of the `-p` parameter:

```
mysql -u root
```

I've also tried providing a number of "common" passwords with the `-p` parameter, but none of them work. I also can't move forward with the `mysql_secure_installation` script due to the same reason.

What is the default password for MariaDB on CentOS 7?

Comment: You could try the `mysql_secure_installation` post-installation script  https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mariadb/how-to-install-mariadb-on-centos-7

Comment: @leonbloy `mysql_secure_installation` also needs the root password. Usually it's empty on most systems, but on CentOS I can't move forward with the script due to this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default password. But it does appear as though one might require a password when attempting to connect to a process that is not running.

Is a `mysql` process running?

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

If not, start it.

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

And connect...

```
mysql -u root
```

Comment: I forgot to look in the most obvious place, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem when I did a reinstall of mariadb, I was not able to logon. I found that when I removed the /var/lib/mysql directory and then installed MariaDB again, I was able to connect as root without password -

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
# yum -y erase mariadb-server
```

Before remove the following directory, make sure that you take the backup in case you need the data.

```
# rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Install the mariadb-server again and do not forget to start it

```
# yum -y install mariadb-server
# systemctl start mariadb
```

Connect as root and just press  when you are prompted for a password.

```
# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 2
Server version: 5.5.60-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> Bye
```

I have not yet investigated this fully, but the idea is to cleanup every bit of the leftover from previous installation and then proceed with a clean installation.

Solved my problem and perhaps can help someone else.